# Producing mean, mode. median for columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I'm trying to calculate mean median and mode for WEIGHT (column name) only for rows that have value of PET_AGE (column name) = 5

I have the following line, but don't know how to extract the values from PET_AGE column that are exactly 5. Could you please help?

`output1 = weights.groupby("PET_AGE")["WEIGHT"].mean().round(2).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: (pet_age_5 is a DataFrame which contains the rows whose PET_AGE is 5)

```py
pet_age_5 = weights[weights["PET_AGE"] == 5]["WEIGHT"]
mean = pet_age_5.mean()
median = pet_age_5.median()
mode = pet_age_5.mode()
```